# All non-ordered pairs between the elements of an array

Tags: code-golf, array, combinatorics

**Task:**

Return an array with **all possible pairs** between the elements of an array.

**Example**

From `a=["a", "b", "c", "d"];` return `b=[["a","b"],["a","c"],["a","d"],["b","c"],["b","d"],["c","d"]]`.

Pairs can be in any order as long as all possible combinations are included and obviously `["b","d"]` is the same to `["d","b"]`.

**Input**

Array of unique string elements composed of chars from the class `[a-z]`.

**Output**

2d array containing all the possible pairs of input array's elements.

**Test Cases**

```
input=["a","b","c"];
//output=[["a","b"],["a","c"],["b","c"]]

input=["a","b","c","d","e"];
//output=[["a","b"],["a","c"],["a","d"],["a","e"],["b","c"],["b","d"],["b","e"],["c","d"],["c","e"],["d","e"]]
```

**Note:** I could not find a ***duplicate*** to this challenge. If there is one, alert me with a comment to drop question.

Comment: I'm not clear on what happens when input values repeat or are not in sorted order. Some more general test cases would help there.

Comment: @Adám Not a dupe, that involves having 2 lists.

Comment: This problem excludes pairing an element with itself, soeven more nonduplicate.

Comment: @xnor havent thought about repeating values because my original problem at work had to do with a unique set of individuals. I guess I should add uniqueness as a condition?

Comment: @alexandros84 Uniqueness would be fine. What should `["c","b","a"]` return?

Comment: @xnor, the same (or not) with ["a","b","c"], in that order of pairs does not matter. This is why I included the wording "non-ordered" in title (this is not legit lingo but impro from my part).

Comment: Edited input for uniqueness. Looks much better now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
Œc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opOT/h9u9HzWtifz/P1opUUlHKQmIk4E4RSkWAA)

Comment: You ninja'd me - pretty print the output using something like `ÇK€Y` in the footer.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Oh, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 29 bytes

```hs
f(a:b)=map((,)a)b++f b
f _=[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcNRCoAgDADQ/04xRh@KniDwJCKxlSNJRar7Lx@8i94716oqhja2odEwxluy7JwALwJ7iEkblQ4BxlP6BysIRCT0yPMxn3PGpD8) Example usage: `f ["a","b","c"]` yields `[("a","b"),("a","c"),("b","c")]`.

---

With the flag `-XTupleSections` this can be shortened to 27 bytes, however the flag would need to be counted:

```hs
f(a:b)=map(a,)b++f b
f _=[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcNBCoAgEADAe69YpENRfSDwFXUIQmI1tyQzyfp@mwOzYzqs98xUYa9reWKssK110xDogmCRs@ITXQAJ8XbhgRIIZoGiFTo3@Zpbofgz5HFL3E3jG70drHncFdIP)

Comment: I think you can save one byte by modifying the be case to `f l=l`.

Comment: @Kritzefitz I'm afraid this won't work as the two empty lists have a different type, so Haskell's type checker will complain.

Comment: Good point. I Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 14 bytes

```
#~Subsets~{2}&
```

**input**

> [{"a", "b", "c"}]

Comment: I was going to do that :(

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell, 25 bytes

```
f l=[(x,y)|x<-l,y<-l,x<y]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hxzZao0KnUrOmwkY3R6cSRFTYVMb@z03MzFOwVUjJ51JQUCgoyswrUVBRSFOIVkpU0lFKAuJkpVjcUjpKKUCcqhT7HwA)

Outer (`x`) and inner (`y`) loop through the input list and keep the pair `(x,y)` only if `x < y`.

Answer (score 6):

### vim, <s>50</s> 48

```
AX<esc>qqYplX@qq@qqrYpllDkxh@rq:g/./norm@r<cr>:g/X/d<cr>dG
```

Takes input in the form

```
abcd
```

and outputs as

```
ad
ac
ab
bd
bc
cd
```

#### Explanation

First, `AX<esc>` appends an `X` to the input in order to handle 2-length input, which is necessary for reasons that will become clear shortly.

Then comes the first recursive macro, of the form `qq...@qq@q`. (Record macro `q`, run itself again at the end, end the recording, then run itself once.) In the body of the macro, `Yp` duplicates the current line, `l` breaks out of the macro if the line is now one character long, and `X` deletes the first character in the line. This has the end result of producing

```
abcdX
abcX
abX
aX
X
X
```

Ignoring the `X`s for now, all we have to do is turn `abcdX`, for example, into `ab / ac / ad / aX`. This is achieved with the second recursive macro, `qr...@rq`.

In this macro, we first duplicate the line (`Yp`), then delete everything but the first two characters by moving right two (`ll`) and deleting to the end of the line (`D`). Since the cursor is now on the second charcater of the line, `kx` will delete the second character from the previous line, which happens to be the one that was just paired with the first character on the line. This process is then repeated starting again from the beginning of the line (`h`) as many times as necessary due to the recursive nature of the macro.

It's now just a matter of running the macro on every line, which can be achieved with `:g/./norm@r` (I'm not sure why this behaves differently than `:%norm@r`, but suffice to say, the latter does not work as intended.) Lines with `X` are deleted with `:g/X/d`, and the blank lines at the end left as a result of the construction of the `r` macro are cleaned up with `dG`.

Comment: Great answer. Will take time for me to go through it.

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
{⊇Ċ}ᶠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v/pRV/uRrtqH2xb8/x@tlKiko6CUBCKSQUSKUuz/KAA)

### How it works

```
{⊇Ċ}ᶠ
    ᶠ   find all the possible outputs of the following predicate
 ⊇          the output is an ordered subset of the input
  Ċ         the output is a list with two elements
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

#### Code:

```
æ2ù
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8DKjwzv//49WSlTSUVBKAhHJICIFRKQqxQIA)

#### Explanation:

```
æ      # Powerset of the input
 2ù    # Keep the items of length two
```

Answer (score 4):

## Octave, 23 bytes

```matlab
@(s)[nchoosek(+s,2) '']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQaNYMzovOSM/vzg1W0O7WMdIU0FdPfZ/Yl6xhlJiUrKS5n8A)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 44 bytes

```python
f=lambda k,*s:[*s]and[[k,x]for x in s]+f(*s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIVtHq9gqWqs4NjEvJTo6W6ciNi2/SKFCITNPoThWO01Dq1jzf0FRZl6JRpqGUqKSjoJSEohIVtLU/A8A)

Takes input as individual function parameters.

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>49</s> 48 bytes

```matlab
@(x)[imag(y=(y=triu(x+j*x',1))(~~y)) real(y) '']
```

Anonymous function that avoids the built-in (`nchoosek`).

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0IzOjM3MV2j0haISooySzUqtLO0KtR1DDU1NerqKjU1FYpSE3M0KjUV1NVj/6dpqCcmJaeoa/4HAA)

#### Explanation

`x+j*x'` uses broadcasting to build a matrix of complex numbers where the real and imaginary parts are all pairs of code points from the input `x`.

`y=triu(...,1)` keeps the upper triangular part excluding the diagonal, making the rest of elements zero. The result is assigned to variable `y`.

`y=(...)(~~y)` retains the nonzero elements in the form of a column vector, which is assigned to variable `y`.

`imag(...)` and `real(...)` extract the real and imaginary parts.

`[... ... '']` converts back to char to build the output.

Comment: Nice! The whole challenge is really interesting. It took me about one hour and a half to come up with my es5 code (featured below). I am happy it generated so many interesting answers..

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 53 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to @CalculatorFeline*

```python
lambda a:[(x,y)for i,x in enumerate(a)for y in a[:i]]
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/Is2V/1)

Comment: `a[i+1:]` can be `a[:i]`

Comment: Having a long username makes short comments easy by simply mentioning the aforementioned user.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 18 bytes

```r
combn(scan(,''),2)
```

reads the list from stdin, returns a matrix where the columns are pairs.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Pzk/NylPozg5MU9DR11dU8dI83@iQpJCskLKfwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 17 bytes

```
*.combinations(2)
```

Whew, that's a long method name.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 34 bytes

```
a->concat([[[x,y]|y<-a,x<y]|x<-a])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9R1y45Py85sUQjOjq6QqcytqbSRjdRp8IGyKoAsmI1/xcUZeaVaKRpRCslKukoJQFxslKspiYXNnEdpRQgTgXJ/wcA)

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, 38 bytes

```matlab
@(s)s([[x y]=find(s|s'),y](y<x,[2 1]))
```

Another answer to avoid `nchoosek` built-in.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQaNYs1gjOrpCoTLWNi0zL0WjuKZYXVOnMlaj0qZCJ9pIwTBWU/N/Yl6xhlJiUnJKqpLmfwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 18 bytes

```arturo
$=>[combine.by:2&]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?LTcG9a)

Answer (score 2):

## Python ≥ 2.7, 55 bytes

```python
lambda l:list(combinations(l,2))
from itertools import*
```

[repl.it!](https://repl.it/Is4a)

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (ES 5), from 108 to 78 bytes

I post my answer today but I obviously promise to not accept my own answer:

```
x=input;
a=[];

for(n=0;n<(x.length-1);n++){for(i=n+1;i<(x.length);i++){a.push([x[n],x[i]]);}}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG; we expect submissions to be golfed, including removing unnecessary whitespace

Comment: Ty. I was wondering also this: should I have included the x=input; a=[]; in my answer or not? I ll edit tomorrow.

Comment: You can either just submit a function or do a full program. Since you use `a`, you need to define it, but you can make a function of `x`.

Comment: much better now @HyperNeutrino.

Comment: I think you can exclude some semicolons and the empty line to save some space. I also think you can change `for(i=n+1;i<(x.length);i++)` to `for(i=n;++i<x.length;)`. Likewise, you can change `n<(x.length-1);n++` to `n++<x.length-1`

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <strike>7</strike> 4 bytes

<sup>-3 bytes thanks to [Leaky Nun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/leaky-nun)!</sup>

```
.cQ2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xy850Oj//2ilRCUdBaUkEJEMIlKUYgE)

Comment: [`.cQ2`](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.cQ2&input=%5B%22a%22%2C+%22b%22%2C+%22c%22%2C+%22d%22%5D&debug=0)?

Comment: @LeakyNun I could have sworn there was a function that did exactly what this challenge needed, but I only saw `.C` when looking through the list. Nice catch!

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 17 bytes

```
_.combinations(2)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 74 bytes

```python
f=lambda a:[(c,d) for i,c in enumerate(a) for j,d in enumerate(a) if i<j]
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can golf this: 1) replace 2-char variable names with 1-char 2) remove unnecessary whitespace 3) this is a snippet, you need to make it into a lambda, function or full program

Comment: Golfing off 10 bytes: [64 bytes](https://tio.run/##NcexCoAgEADQva@4UeGWspbIL6mGK086KQuxoa83CHrbu568ndEUb6ey07E4AkK2HO@DE2XuR7Wi0/5MILiCRGBFXwO6v@JBhjCX6koSs/JqrLFBgy12s9blBQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 bytes

```
à2
```

[Test it](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=4DI=&input=WyJhIiwiYiIsImMiLCJkIiwiZSJdCi1R) (`-Q` flag for visualisation purposes only)

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 64 bytes

```
f=lambda a:sum((list(zip(a, a[i:]))for i in range(1,len(a))),[])
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>38 34</s> 24 bytes

```ruby
->x{[*x.combination(2)]}
```

Thanks Seims for the idea that saved 10 bytes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166iOlqrQi85PzcpMy@xJDM/T8NIM7b2f4FCWnS0UqKSjoJSEohIVoqN/Q8A)

Comment: `->x{x.combination(2).to_a}` saves some bytes :)

Answer (score 2):

### Clojure, 42 bytes

```
#(set(for[i % j(remove #{i}%)](set[i j])))
```

Returns a set of sets :)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 17 bytes

```
({~$#:I.@,)#\</#\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03B1kpBo7pORdnKU89BR1M5xkZfOYaLKzU5I18hTUE9MSk5Rf3/fwA)

### Explanation

```
({~$#:I.@,)#\</#\  Input: string S
               #\  Get the length of each prefix of S
           #\      Get the length of each prefix of S again
             </    Test using greater than (<) between each
         ,         Flatten
      I.@          Find the indices where the value is 1
   $               Shape of that table
    #:             Convert the indices to the base represented by the shape
 {~                Index into S at those values
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), `-p` 4 bytes

```
aCB2
```

`CB` is the operator for combinations, not much explanation needed

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJhQ0IyIiwiIiwiIiwiJ1tcImFcIjtcImJcIjtcImNcIjtcImRcIl0nIC14cCJd)

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 132 bytes

```go
func f[T any](S[]T)(O[][]T){if len(S)<3{O=append(O,S)}else{for a,i:=range(S){for _,j:=range(S[a+1:]){O=append(O,[]T{i,j})}}}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZBBSgMxGIVxO2dwEbJKMAq1ClLsGUaY7kIov9NkSJ3JDGlmISE7b-FmEHqIHkVPYzIVsWLVzfuT9778PPL8UrXDroPyASqJGtAm003XWneBVePwtnfq_Ob1SfWmRIovEJhHQQouFpTkXKTptUK1NKSgt1Ofz6HrpFmRnBU0yHojvWotAqZncwumkhEbnSVbfzocziYzQb8-jou9ZutAQwiZla63Juy7vJ2cjmVSVUKRz-6sNq42RBEuNi5eKo8BM4Tvk5Q4UPonE2X1fzCKHOkDPJ789xXJm_xosssjNpseDdjVLxG7TuHHJw3Dfr4D)

A generic function that takes in a slice of type `T` and outputs a slice of slices of type `T`.

A solution that does only `[]string -> [][]string` is 8 bytes longer.

#### Explanation

```go
func f[T any](S[]T)(O[][]T){  // boilerplate
if len(S)<3{                  // if the input length < 3,
  O=append(O,S)               // just return the input
}else{                        // otherwise,
  for a,i:=range(S){          // for each 1st element,
    for _,j:=range(S[a+1:]){  // and each 2nd element,
      O=append(O,[]T{i,j})}}} // add the pair
return}                       // return the result
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, 52 bytes

```
a=>a.map((x,i)=>a.slice(0,i).map(y=>[x,y])).slice(1)
```

If there was like a `flatMap` that would save a lot of bytes.

Comment: Hey nice answer! check out my es5 answer while I study yours if u want. any feedback will be appreciated (positive/constructive haha)

Comment: Firefox 30's array comprehensions can simulate a flat map, e.g. `a=>[for(x of[...a])for(y of(a.shift(),a))[x,y]]`.

Comment: @Neil, some really advanced syntax there... I d have to google at least three things to start understanding your expression. Namely the spread operator, what is array comprehensions and what is the [x,y] in the end (still havent found answer to that).

Comment: @alexandros84 The `[x,y]` at the end is the easy bit, it's just an array literal.

Comment: Also the spread operator is only there to copy the array, since I'm mutating it inside the loop.

Comment: @Neil it took me like one hour and a half to find my solution to my own challenge (earlier today for a problem at work-- my code is the last answer here). Still have lots to learn about js, especially now that es6 is becoming widespread.

Comment: The output seems to be wrapped inside an extra layer of `[ ]`?

Comment: @Neil I ve entered your expression inside babeljs.io online tool and for some reason I get unexpected token. I ve learned a lot from your contribution and I am really grateful for it, but why is this happening? Hey wait... I think I found out why: (from mdn on array comprehensions) "Specifications: Was initially in the ECMAScript 2015 draft, but got removed in revision 27 (August 2014). Please see older revisions of ES2015 for specification semantics."

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 55 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:[(s[0],j)for j in s[1:]]+f(s[1:])if s else[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcYxDoAgDADAr3SjRAd1JPElhAGERggCoSy@HhNvuvaOu5ZjTjqzfZy3wEoj682sSVLtkCAWYL0rYxbCPzISMITMQZvZeiwDkFBYd/kgpJwf)

Longer than other Python answers, but it uses a different technique so I think it's worth posting.

Comment: Dont have time to check, I hope is really different technique cause I ve upvoted.

Comment: I think this is a very similar approach to @ovs's Python 3 answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 1.5 bytes

```
`_~
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWixPi6yAsqMBN5Wil6BilxBglnRilJDCZDCZTwGRqjFKsUixULQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 3 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 2.47 bytes

```
2zQ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaLjaoCISyowIK10eqJ6jrqSUCcrB4LEQQA)

Almost a built-in. `zQ` is "combinations of b with length a".

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
2ḋ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIy4biLIiwiIiwiW1wiYVwiLFwiYlwiLFwiY1wiXSJd)

Almost a built-in. `ḋ` is the built-in for "combinations of a with length b"

Answer (score 1):

## [Curry (PAKCS)](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/index.html), 20 bytes

```
f(_++x:_++y:_)=[x,y]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m706ubSoqDK-IDE7uXjBgqWlJWm6FlvSNOK1tSusgESlVbymbXSFTmUsRGpDbmJmnoKtQpqCUmJSckqqEkQYphMA)

Comment: I learning Curry now and like it very much. But is there some _prime numbers_ built in, can you help me?

Comment: @lesobrod There isn't such built-in in [Prelude](https://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/~cpm/DOC/base-3.1.0/Prelude.html) or the [base library](https://cpm.curry-lang.org/pkgs/base.html). I can't even find any package for number theory in the [CPM Repository](https://cpm.curry-lang.org/).

Comment: @lesobrod By the way, you can claim [this bounty](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25453/9288) for your first Curry answer.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try. And may be will try to make some primes generator in Smap

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
2ċ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPTIlQzQlOEImZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0lNUIlMjJhJTIyJTJDJTIyYiUyMiUyQyUyMmMlMjIlMkMlMjJkJTIyJTJDJTIyZSUyMiU1RCZmbGFncz0=)

`ċ` = "all combinations of b with length a"